# Calabash: How do i perform a certain action till i reach the last element in the ListView in my Android app

Tags: android

I am trying to automate my Android App. Now there is a list view which has a filter option. Based on the selection of filter, the list can show either 1 or (lets say) 20 elements. I want to go through all these 20 elements

Currently i am not able to identify the break condition for the loop when all these 20 elements are done being read.

example:

```
    no_of_items = 0
    begin

      res = performAction('get_list_item_text','2')['bonusInformation']

      item_count = res.count
      performAction('scroll_down')

      verify_distance_value(filter_option, @test_data[type][filter_option]) 
                                     ######--> Function to verify the elements on the listView
      no_of_items = no_of_items + item_count
    end while (no_of_items < item_count.to_i + 16) ########--> what should be this condition
```

Answer (score 0):

several different ways

- you could check how many items in the list, e.g. for a GridView, you can get its Adapter, then get item count. 
  query(“GridView”, “getAdapter”, “getCount”)
  notes that getAdapter is a function of GridView, getCount is a func of the view Adapter. should be the same for listview
- after scroll, you can check the text of the last item, compare with the last one before scroll-down. if they are the same, means ...